# Changing one recurrence into another.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Let $p_n = (n-1)p_{n-1} + (n-1)p_{n-2}$ for $n>1$ and $p_0 = 1, p_1 = 0$

Show that the following recurrence is equal...

$p_n = n*p_{n - 1} + (-1)^n$ for $n > 0$ and $p_0 = 1$.

How would you go about showing that the first recurrence can be changed into the second?

Comment: Hint: induction.

Answer (score 1):

Since$$p_n = (n-1)p_{n-1} + (n-1)p_{n-2}$$
can be written as
$$p_n-np_{n-1}=-(p_{n-1}-(n-1)p_{n-2})$$
we have
$$\begin{align}p_n-np_{n-1}&=-(p_{n-1}-(n-1)p_{n-2})\\\\&=(-1)^2(p_{n-2}-(n-2)p_{n-3})\\\\&=\cdots \\\\&=(-1)^{n-1}(p_1-1\cdot p_0)\\\\&=(-1)^n\end{align}$$